# Kotlin. Can I get all Objects that implements specific interface

Tags: kotlin

I have something like:

```
interface Options {
    fun load(conf: JsonObject)
}

object BasicOptions : Options { }
object PersonOptions : Options { }
object CarOptions : Options { }
```

then I would like to get all `Objects` that implements Options `interface` and call load `forEach`.

```
fun main(args: Array) {
    configFuture.whenComplete { config ->
            options.forEach { it.load(config) }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you have to create a list (or similar) yourself to keep track of the objects.

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported by the language, this is why there are Dependency Injection, Registry, or Service Lookup solutions.

- If all objects are registered in a Dependency Injection framework, you may be able to iterate all objects registered to the framework and find the instances of your Interface.

  - This is likely to be rather inefficient - so cache the results to avoid the extra overhead.
- Another approach is to use custom class loader and add this custom functionality. The simplest way is probably using the [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library, to scan and load these classes. E.g.:

  ```
  val reflections = Reflections("my.project.prefix")
  val allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Options::class.java)
  ```
- The simplest, and most commonly used solution would be simply maintain your own "registry" e.g. a static object holding the list of all instances. It will require manually adding any new class implementing the interface - but it will be simple, performant, and robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can!

Using the [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library it's really easy:

First, you need to find all the **java classes** that implement your interface "Objects". Then you convert the java classes to **kotlin classes** (KClass).

KClass has the property **objectInstance** that is null if the class does not have an object instance... otherwise IS the *singleton* object instance.

So:

```
val reflections = Reflections(ConfigurationBuilder())
val jList = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Options::class.java)
val kList = jList.map { it.kotlin }
val oList = kList.map { it.objectInstance }.filterNotNull()
```

;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `Factory` pattern for creating new instances of `Options`, that way you can have your own `OptionsFactory` and your own caching mechanism.

That `OptionsFactory` after instantiating an object keeps it in cache (could be in-memory cache or DB..etc), then anytime you can ask the factory for it's cached instances when needed.

This is fairly better when your `Options` objects are created in run-time/upon demand.